# TeXMaker can't find my own class file

Tags: errors, texmaker, document-classes, paths

I've been using `TeXMaker` for a while now and it usually works fine. A couple of months ago i wrote my own class and style files, started to use them and it worked fine. I had placed the `.cls` and `.sty` files in the same directory as the `.tex` files that were using it.
The problem is that I've started to use the class and style in multiple places and thus wanted to move the `.cls` and `.sty` files to the C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base directory so that I didn't have to copy them to every directory where they're used.

After doing this I get the error code

```
"! LaTeX Error: File `CV.cls' not found."
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Welcome! Check out [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files) There is an answer for MikTeX, which is slightly different to TeX Live.

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to place own files in to the LaTeX base directory.

Answer (score 2):

The above mentioned link may not be sufficiciently detailed. So here are some more information.

First you create a `local` TeXMF directory, say `C:\LocalTeXMF` and declare it to your MiKTeX system through `MiKTeX Settings` (as administrator), `Root` tab, `Add` button:

[image]

In that directory, put you class/style files in a directory of their own, respecting the TeX Directory Structure, for instance `C:\LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\CV\`. Check you files don't have the same name as another existing file. If you have a documentation file, put it in `C:\LocalTeXMF\doc\latex\CV\`.

Finally, refresh the database of files, always through MiKTeX Settings, `General` tab, `Refresh FNDB` button:

[image]

Your files are now ready to be used from anywhere on your computer.